# Is there a specified procedure in Classic Traveller for generating secondary worlds?

Tags: traveller

I am asking specifically about Classic Traveller; the "Little Black Books."

LBB-3 gives the procedure for generating subsector maps. That includes a procedure for generating the primary world in a system.

Is there a defined procedure for generating the other worlds in a system? I've looked through the material I have access to, and haven't found anything.

Obviously, I can make up my own, and I'm confident in my ability to do so. However, I really do want to find an as-written answer. The ideal one would be either "Yes, it's in ___", or "I am confident there is no such procedure," or "Nothing explicit, but there was a standard practice, which you can see mentioned in JTAS ___".

Again, I am only looking for Classic Traveller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes! Rules for generating entire star systems can be found in *Book 6 Scouts*.** In 20 glorious pages, these rules let you generate the number, type, and luminosity of a system's stars, its habitable zones, its gas giants, its planetoid belts, its rocky planets (and their UPPs), its satellites (and *their* UPPs), and pretty much everything else you could possibly need.

The rules support both generating entire systems from scratch, and taking the UPPs from your existing sector map and retrofitting star systems around them, making it relatively easy to add to an ongoing Traveller campaign.

I don't know if it's still possible to get *Book 6 Scouts* in print, but digital copies can be [purchased online](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/80174/Classic-TravellerCT-B06Scouts?term=book%206%20scouts).

Comment: Perfect; that’s exactly what I was missing!